# How to pass an action?

Tags: haskell, types

Apologies for the long code sample, please refer just to line 30: `A.openDeviceCallback =` . `micSpec` is a factory function for objects of type [A.OpenDeviceSpec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sdl2-2.2.0/docs/SDL-Audio.html). I am unhappy with this function's parameter list.

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}


-- Dependant on cabal packages: sdl2, wave.


module Main where


import qualified Control.Concurrent as C
--import qualified Control.Monad as M
import qualified Data.Vector.Storable.Mutable as V
import qualified Data.Set as S
import Foreign.ForeignPtr as P

import qualified SDL
import qualified SDL.Audio as A

import qualified Codec.Audio.Wave as W

import qualified System.IO as IO

import qualified Statistics.Sample as St


micSpec :: IO.Handle -> A.OpenDeviceSpec
micSpec h = A.OpenDeviceSpec {A.openDeviceFreq = A.Mandate 48000
                             ,A.openDeviceFormat = A.Mandate A.Signed16BitNativeAudio
                             ,A.openDeviceChannels = A.Mandate A.Mono
                             ,A.openDeviceSamples = 4096
                             ,A.openDeviceCallback = \_ (V.MVector size ptr) -> P.withForeignPtr ptr (\p -> IO.hPutBuf h p size)
                             ,A.openDeviceUsage = A.ForCapture
                             ,A.openDeviceName = Nothing}


waveSpec :: W.Wave
waveSpec = W.Wave {W.waveFileFormat = W.WaveVanilla
                  , W.waveSampleRate = 48000
                  , W.waveSampleFormat = W.SampleFormatPcmInt 16
                  , W.waveChannelMask = S.singleton W.SpeakerFrontCenter
                  , W.waveDataOffset = 0
                  , W.waveDataSize = 0
                  , W.waveSamplesTotal = 0
                  , W.waveOtherChunks = []}


record :: IO.Handle -> IO ()
record h = do
  SDL.initialize [SDL.InitAudio]
  (dev, _) <- A.openAudioDevice $ micSpec h
  A.setAudioDevicePlaybackState dev A.Play
--  _ <- M.forever (C.threadDelay maxBound)
  _ <- C.threadDelay 10000000
  return ()


main :: IO ()
main =  W.writeWaveFile "mic.rec" waveSpec record
```

In the context of such a simple program, the needed `A.OpenDeviceSpec` object is a set of constants, plus an action. Currently, the action is being constructed inline ... because that was the only way I managed to define it, without passing type information around.

My intuition from C is in the lines of

```
type Cb =  A.AudioFormat t -> A.IOVector t -> IO () 
micSpec :: Cb -> A.OpenDeviceSpec
```

, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: That link is broken.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question fully.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson how can I define a function `Int -> IO() -> Int`? Is this possible or sensible?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your issue has to do with the *universally-quantised field*

```
data OpenDeviceSpec = OpenDeviceSpec {
    ...
  , openDeviceCallback :: forall actualSampleType. AudioFormat actualSampleType -> IOVector actualSampleType -> IO ()
  , ...
  }
```

...or, as it can be written more briefly,

```
data OpenDeviceSpec = OpenDeviceSpec {
    ...
  , openDeviceCallback :: ∀ sT . AudioFormat sT -> IOVector sT -> IO ()
  , ...
  }
```

Don't worry, this is nothing difficult. In fact such a `∀` is implicit in all of the standard polymorphic functions, e.g.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

is actually shorthand<sup>†</sup> for

```
map :: ∀ a b . (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Likewise, to define your callback you just need to make sure it's *polymorphic in the sample type*. I.e.

```
openingCallback :: IO.Handle -> A.AudioFormat sT -> V.IOVector sT -> IO ()
openingCallback _ (V.MVector size ptr)
       = P.withForeignPtr ptr $ \p -> IO.hPutBuf h p size
```

and then

```
micSpec h = A.OpenDeviceSpec {
                              ...
                             ,A.openDeviceCallback = openingCallback h
                             ,...
                             }
```

If you want to have `openingCallback` as an argument to `micSpec`, you need to make that argument universally-quantified too. Like record fields and unlike top-level bindings, arguments must be declared with an explicit quantor to be universal:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types, UnicodeSyntax #-}
micSpec :: (∀ sT . A.AudioFormat sT -> V.IOVector sT -> IO ())
               -> A.OpenDeviceSpec
micSpec openingCallback
          = A.OpenDeviceSpec {
                              ...
                             ,A.openDeviceCallback = openingCallback
                             ,...
                             }
```

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Well, I'm not sure if it really makes sense to put it this way, because `∀` isn't even legal in Haskell98. Still, the universal quantifier is how all polymorphic signatures should be read.</sub>